# How to find out the odd integers in an array using a recursive method?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am trying to write a method that finds how many odd numbers are between first position and last position. The method accepts an array, and then two `int`s for the low and high position. This method needs to be made recursively. Here is what I have so far. Here is the method call and the int array. I'm getting an output of 1 but the answer should be 2.

```
int array [] = {5, 2, 5, 6, 3, 1};
int n = countOddsInRange(array, 1, 4)

public static int countOddsInRange(int [] a, int first, int last)
{
    int count = 0;
    if(first <= last)
    {
        countOddsInRange(a, a[first + 1], a[last]);
        if(a[first] % 2 == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some bugs in your code :

1. You are counting even numbers, not odd. Change your condition to `if(a[first] % 2 != 0)`
2. The recursive call should get indices of the array, not the values in those locations.
3. You should add the result of the recursive call to the total : `count+=countOddsInRange(a, first + 1, last)`

To summarize :

```
public static int countOddsInRange(int [] a, int first, int last)
{
    int count = 0;
    if(first <= last)
    {
        count+=countOddsInRange(a, first + 1, last);
        if(a[first] % 2 != 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should looks like :

```
public static int countOddNumber(int [] a, int first, int last){
    return countOddNumber(a, first, last, 0);
}

public static int countOddNumber(int [] a, int first, int last, int count){
    //in recursive function start with termination test.
    if (first == last){
        return count + isOdd(a[first]);
    }
    else{
        return countOddNumber(a, first+1, last, count) + isOdd(a[first]);
    }
}

public static int isOdd(int number){
    if(number%2 == 0){return 1;}
    else{return 0}
}
```

You should also add a test to check if first is lesser than last to avoid infinite loop ;)

PS : filter element whose mod(element,2) = 0 and then get the size of the collection. That method use functional style too, and use new Java8 feature. And is probably much more faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CountOddsInRange {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array[] = {5, 2, 5, 6, 3, 1};
    int n = countOddsInRange(array, 0, array.length - 1, 0);
    System.out.println("No of odds is " + n);
}

public static int countOddsInRange(int[] a, int first, int last, int count) {
  if (first <= last) {
    if (a[first] % 2 != 0) {
      count++;
    }
    return countOddsInRange(a, first + 1, last, count);
  }
  return count;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CountOddsInRange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[] = {5, 2, 5, 6, 3, 1};
        int n = countOddsInRange(array, 0, array.length - 1);
        System.out.println("No of odds is " + n);
    }

    public static int countOddsInRange(int [] a, int first, int last)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if(first <= last)
        {
            count+=countOddsInRange(a, first + 1, last);
            if(a[first] % 2 != 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;   
   }
}
```